# How do I get this function to return a date-time-string

Tags: c++, datetime

I have the following function that for the life of me I cannot get to return a string:

```
void GetDateTimeString()
{
    auto t1 = std::time(nullptr);
    auto tm1 = *std::localtime(&t1);
    stringstream dattim1;
    cout << put_time(&tm1, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S");
}
```

I have tried this in vain, which crashes the program:

```
std::string GetDateTimeString()
{
    time_t t1 = std::time(nullptr);
    tm tm1 = *std::localtime(&t1);
    stringstream dattim1;
    dattim1 << put_time(&tm1, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S");
    std::string returnValue = dattim1.str();
    return returnValue;
}
```

In the end I want to call it like this:

```
string dateString = GetDateTimeString();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281293/timestamps-for-embedded-system/31281976#31281976

Comment: TBH your second example looks fine and works for me.

Comment: Hm. Maybe the problem I am having, is that I am not using C++11? My code is still running on Visual Studio 2010. Could that be it? If so how would I achieve this given my configuration? It is some old legacy code that is in C/C++ (some ugly mix actually) and I want to do minimal work on it, since my plan is to rewrite it in C# in the future. But good to know that in principle it should work - was sort of losing my mind today! :)

Answer (score 1):

The first version of your function is of type `void` so it does not return anything. `cout` will just print the time e.g. to the console.

In the second function you try to use `put_time` again, but that is the wrong function for your demand. instead use `strftime` to copy the time to a `char-array` and then to a `string`:

```
std::string GetDateTimeString()
{
    time_t t1 = std::time(nullptr);
    tm tm1 = *std::localtime(&t1);
    char buffer[80];
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", &tm1);
    std::string returnValue(buffer);
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the code works in a simple test, but crashes in your application, I would suggest you look at using localtime_s or localtime_r (system dependent) instead of localtime, which returns a pointer to a static buffer, and is not threadsafe.