# Return value of std::strftime

Tags: c++, c, glibc

I think I read somewhere that if I pass a nullptr to [std::strftime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime), the function would return the required buffer size. And indeed, the following code works perfectly well on numerous linux systems I've tried it on (not when compiled with VS though):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::time_t time{};
    std::tm const * ltime = std::localtime(&time);

    const char * formatString = "%Y-%b-%d";
    //allocate buffer of appropriate size
    auto requiredSize = 1 + std::strftime(nullptr, 50, formatString, ltime);
    std::cout << "Required buffer size:" << requiredSize << "\n";

    //Format time to string
    std::string buff(requiredSize, ' ');
    std::strftime(&buff[0], requiredSize, formatString, ltime);

    std::cout << buff << std::endl;
}
```

However, I was unable to find my original source or any other documentation that would specify this behavior. So my question is:

- On which systems / compilers / standard library implementations (if any) is this a guaranteed behavior?
- Where can I find the according documentation?

Edit: I added the C label, as I've seen the same result with equivalent C code and at least with gcc/g++ (or rather glibc/libstdc++) `std::strftime` is probably just an alias for the c-function `strftime` anyway.

Comment: IIRC what you're claiming works. I think cppreference needs an update about this.

Comment: Documentation:  Check out one of the drafts for the latest C++ standard.  It documents the library functions (but possibly by referring to a C standard).  Note that there is a general rule "you can't pass NULL to a library function unless it explicitly says you can".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The thing is that neither in the C nor C++ standard (at least in the versions I can find in the internet) I can find any reference to this. Nor in the according man pages on the linux systems I tested it on.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Thanks, but I know, where to look for the documentation for ISO C or C++ but couldn't find any reference to this behavior in either of those documents (which doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't exist). Apparently this isn't even mentioned in the POSIX spec, which often requires additional functionality (e.g. POSIX specified multithreading behavior long befor ISO C or C++ did).

Comment: I think its more efficient to create a stack buffer and then construct the `std::string` directly passing the address of the stack buffer and the return value of `std::strftime()`, passing it the same stack buffer along with the rest of the format parameters.Then `std::strftime` fills the stack buffer and returns the correct length to construct the `std:string` directly. That saves calling `st::strftime` twice and filling the `std::string` twice.

Comment: Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281293/timestamps-for-embedded-system/31281976#31281976

Comment: This looks like undefined behavior to me.  strftime does not have any requirement in the C standard to do what you say and it does say *If the total number of resulting characters including the terminating null character is not more than maxsize, the strftime function returns the number of characters placed into the array pointed to by s not including the terminating null character.* so it looks to me like it will attempt to write into the array and doing that is UB.

Comment: @Galik: Thank you. You are most probably right and this was certainly not meant as demonstration of how to best use `strftime`. I came across something similar in some older code of mine (while porting it to windows) and was surprised that I didn't find anything about this in the Linux/POSIX documentation.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I agree, that is UB according to the ISO C and C++ standard. But just because something is UB in the ISO-C or C++ standard doesn't necessarily mean it is not specified for an actual standard library implementation that might (in addition) adhere to other standards like POSIX.

Comment: @mikemb: it is not in posix either. It is probably an undocumented glibc extension.

Comment: @rici: Thank you very much. You were absolutely right just that it is documented and I was to stupid to search at the right place.

Comment: Neither C11 nor POSIX (2008, 2013) mandates the 'return the number of characters that would have been printed' behaviour.  However, it parallels the behaviour of `snprintf()` which is mandated to behave sanely like that, so there is precedent for the specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell and as others have wrote in the comments, above code is most probably undefined behavior according to the ISO C or C++ standard and as far as my own experiments are concerned will crash when compiled with VS2015.

However, as far as glibc is concerned, @rici was spot on:

From the documentation of [The GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Calendar-Time.html):

> If s is a null pointer, strftime does not actually write anything, but instead returns the number of characters it would have written.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you'd mention that this behavior is not specified by the C or C++ standard or by POSIX. For implementations other than glibc, passing a null pointer as the first argument to `strftime` has undefined behavior. (Of course returning useful information is entirely consistent with undefined behavior.)

Comment: A quibble: This is a glibc issue; it has nothing directly to do with gcc or g++. For example, you can use clang or clang++ with glibc, and you can use gcc or g++ with other library implementations.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Fixed. Thank you.