# Format microseconds in Wt C++

Tags: c++

What is the best way to format microseconds in C++ Wt or Qt library. I tried like this, "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffff" but I am not able to get the last decimal values of 1753-01-01T00:00:02.**000004**.

Regards
Ansif

Comment: What is your input?  Are you sure it has fractional seconds?  Can you post an example of what you tried?

Comment: This answer may (or may not) be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281293/timestamps-for-embedded-system/31281976#31281976

Comment: Did anyone tries using WDateTime in Wt/C++ toolkit. You can find the default format like "yyyy MM dd hh mm ss". The format shows upto seconds. But what if we have values like 1753-01-01T00:00:02.000004. The last value "000004" is microsecond. I was looking for a proper way to format the values in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansif, could you not just use:

```
WString value = myDate.toString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:MM:ss");

double microsecond = ...; // get the microsecond from myDate somehow
```

Then append the microsecond like so:

```
WString myDate2 = WString("{1}.{2}").arg(myDate).arg(microsecond);
```

Since Wt's precision is only three decimal places for milliseconds you would have to add the microsecond part yourself up to six decimal places and convert it to a std::string, std::stringstream or WString() if I understand you correctly.

If using std::stringstream to convert the microseconds to a std::string, then std::setw, std::setfill, std::fixed and std::setprecision might be helpful for padding the "000004" microseconds.